# Keyboard Shortcuts in Excel Menu CommandBar

Tags: excel, menuitem, excel-2003, vba

The code below adds a menu item *Custom1* right before *New...*. How can I get the keyboard shortcut assigned to *CodeCustom1* (via `Application.OnKey`) to appear nicely right-aligned with *Ctrl+N*?

```
Sub menuItem_Create()
   With CommandBars("Worksheet menu bar").Controls("File")
      .Controls.Add(Type:=msoControlButton, Before:=1).Caption = "Custom1"
      .Controls("Custom1").OnAction = "CodeCustom1"
   End With
End Sub
```

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the CommandbarButton's `ShortcutText` property:

```
.Controls("Custom1").ShortcutText = "ctrl+W"
```

Comment: It's tricky because `CommandbarButton` is a subset of `CommandbarControl` and has a few more properties. When in doubt, declare it as a button, and you'll be able to better see what's available.